# Style of figures compared to the overall layout

Tags: typography

Two questions regarding your subjective perception:

> Should figures be typeset in the *same* or a *different* style than the document?

and

> How "bad" is using a different font-size within figures?

I mean an intentional decision for LaTeX-typeset figures -- not the "third-party plotting-app"-discrepancy.

One could argue that figures using the same style (e.g. [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17687213/how-to-obtain-the-same-font-style-size-etc-in-matplotlib-output-as-in-latex)) fit in smoothly.

One could also argue that figures provide *supplementary* information where a typographical distinction (e.g. sans-serif) can be helpful guiding the reader.

Looking forward to your thoughts. :-)

---

P.s.: My question is especially with regard to data-plots.

Comment: This seems to be highly subject dependent, someone commented the other day that they wanted figure text to be in sans but the body text in roman by default. I (with a math background) commented that that seemed somewhat bizarre choice but it was confirmed in chat that it is the norm in (at least) Chemistry and a requirement for many publications in that area. So basically "do what the publisher requires" seems like a good rule for getting stuff published...

Comment: I agree when you want to get stuff published -- But these constraints can be ridiculous (the origin of some is explained in the `KOMA` documentation). Here, I am interested in personal opinions about *good typesetting*.